# Strict constraints for the same columns don't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

[image]

When users supply filters on a web-site, I'm receiving a collection of `group_id` with ther corresponding `value_id` parameters.
For example, the input of collection might look like this:

```
Array(
    '4' => '7',
    '2' => '4'
)
```

So, I'm trying to select rows by received contraints and the match has to be strict by these contraints, and that's the problem. 
Nothing of what I tried works as expected.

Here's the first obvious thing that should work (because there are exact matches in the table), but it doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE

    (group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') 
        AND 
    (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')
```

Then I've tried to select using `IN` operator, which works, but isn't really strict since its internally based on `OR` operators. 
For example this query (note I replaced `2` with `13`) must return nothing, since there's no match 13=7 (group_id = value)

```
SELECT * FROM bono_module_shop_product_attributes WHERE

(group_id IN ('4', '13') AND value_id IN ('6', '7'))
```

but it returns one row.

So my question here is, in terms of SQL logic, how to make this query work:

```
SELECT * FROM product_attributes WHERE

    (group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') 
        AND 
    (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')
```

?

Comment: `(group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') OR (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')` Note: `(group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') AND (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')` == `group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7' AND group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4'` == `group_id = '4' AND group_id = '2' AND value_id = '7' AND value_id = '4'` == `(group_id = '4' AND group_id = '2') AND (value_id = '7' AND value_id = '4')`, obviously you do not have any row where `group_id` is `'4'` and `'2'` in the same time.

Comment: What output do you actually want here?

Comment: @PetSerAl No `OR` operator doesn't make the selection strict. For example, If I supply `...OR (group_id = '20'` (i.e non-existing `group_id` value) it would select only one row, which is undesireable. It must select none.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Consider the following logical expression: 
When `(group_id=4 && value_id=7) and (group_id=2 && value_id=4)` it must select two corresponding rows. It's that simple. In case that logical expression isn't true, then nothing should be selected.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `(group_id=4 && value_id=7) and (group_id=2 && value_id=4)` That logical expression is never true, so nothing selected.

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, look but those values are in the table, so why the expression isn't true?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `(group_id=4 && value_id=7) and (group_id=2 && value_id=4)` == `(group_id=4 && group_id=2) and (value_id=7 && value_id=4)`. **`group_id=4 && group_id=2`** that is false for every row in you table.

Comment: If I guessed correctly what you really want: `select product_id from product_attributes group by product_id having max(group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') and max(group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to use condtional aggregation to check that *both* records are present.  Then, use a `WHERE` condition which checks for the presence of *either* record, along with the requirement that both are present together.

```
SELECT *
FROM product_attributes
WHERE ((group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') OR
      (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')) AND
      (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (group_id = '4' AND value_id = '7') OR
                            (group_id = '2' AND value_id = '4')
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       FROM product_attributes) = 2
```

Comment: You're most probably missing something to link back the sub-select to the lines you're matching in the "outer" select.

Comment: `You're most probably missing something` ... nothing is missing, as this query should already be working.  If you can phrase the answer differently, feel free to provide another answer.

Comment: Your subselect will return 2 as long as there are two lines matching those conditions, whether they are linked to the same product or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you really want is the `product_id`, not the individual matched lines.

Then you need to match on several lines of the `product_attributes` table, each of which matches one of your `group_id, value_id` selections, AND which all match the same product.

```
SELECT pa1.product_id
    FROM product_attributes pa1
    JOIN product_attributes pa2 ON pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
    WHERE pa1.group_id = 4 AND pa1.value_id = 7
    AND pa2.group_id = 2 AND pa2.value_id = 4
```

Another option is use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT product_id
    FROM product_attributes
    WHERE (group_id = 4 AND value_id = 7)
    OR (group_id = 2 AND value_id = 4)
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This will get ugly when dealing with more than a pair of values.

Comment: Why would it? You would of course generate the query programmatically, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I thought of giving your answer, but the OP did not ask for it.

Comment: This query has a problem: It will count 2 if the _same_ group/value pair should appear twice.

Comment: Not sure if you saw the comments + edit, but there was an incorrect `AND` which needs to be `OR` of course (in the second query).